# How do I save current user in another table when saving objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form where users will enter their traincar information. When saved, I also want to save the current user in the table. I have a one-to-many relationship built in my models, but can't get the user into my save method.  I've tried using ApplicationUser a number of ways but can't get it to post correctly.  Here is my current save method:

```
  public void SaveCar(Cars carToSave) {
        if (carToSave.Id == 0) {
            _db.Cars.Add(carToSave);
            _db.SaveChanges();
        } else {
            var original = this.Find(carToSave.Id);
            original.EmptyOrLoaded = carToSave.EmptyOrLoaded;
            original.CarType = carToSave.CarType;
            original.ShippedBy = carToSave.ShippedBy;
            original.RailcarNumber = carToSave.RailcarNumber;
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

And my model class:

```
 namespace Train.Models {
public class Cars {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EmptyOrLoaded { get; set; }
    public string CarType { get; set; }
    //Hopper, flatbed, tank, gondola, etc.
    public string ShippedBy { get; set; }
    //UP(Union Pacific) or BNSF
    public string RailcarNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

}
```

And IdentityModels.cs

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {
    [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "About is limited to 250 characters in length.")]
    public string Company { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Cars> Cargroup { get; set; }
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, string authenticationType) {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> {

    public IDbSet<Cars> Cars { get; set; }
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false) {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create() {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your model class please?

Comment: edited original to add model

Comment: Thanks. And your User class? If you want to post User data through Car, User must be a property of Car model class.

Comment: edited to add Identity Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save only the reference to the current user.

```
User.Identity.GetUserId();//this will return your UserID
```

**EDIT**: `User.Identity` is available in your Controllers if they inherit `Controller`

Comment: Thanks!  I've tried that a few times and just can't get it right.  Where do I put it?

Comment: @ScottVMeyers You should put it in your controller, the User.Identity is available there.

Comment: Okay, I think I've got that, but don't I still need to save it in my save method as well?

Comment: @ScottVMeyers if you want to put UserID in your Cars, you should defined in the model as Guid and when you give your Car to SaveCar method you should assign the car.UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();

Comment: dangit, ya lost me.  I've got it added as a parameter in my save method in my controller

Comment: Got it!  Whew, that was wayyy easier than I was making it.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @ScottVMeyers yep :) Good luck with your solution.